# OpenSSH Client Windows 10 is not found

Tags: windows-10, openssh

I have OpenSSH client installed on Windows 10:

[image]

But when I change to the OpenSSH directory and list it the client (ssh.exe) is not there:

[image]

And when I go to use the command it's not found:
[image]

The OpenSSH directory is in my path:

[image]

How can I get the OpenSSH client working on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a path issue. Try `c:\windows\system32\openssh\ssh`. If this works, append the directory of OpenSSH in your PATH.

Comment: The OpenSSH directory is already on my path. I've updated the OP to show that. Also as I note in the OP the `sshd.ext` does not exist in the OpenSSH directory.

Comment: @TimDunphy - What exactly is **sshd.ext**?

Comment: That's the OpenSSH server command that I'm not interested in using. I only want to ssh out from my windows machine, not in.